# Pop up window in Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I see a pop up window when ever i move my cursor into any of the textbox in this [website](http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client).
How to create those in bootstrap ?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation. You are probably referring to modals. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was done with Bootstrap's [Popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

Here is their code:

```
$(function() {

  // Set up the help menus.
  var help_divs = $('.control-group').filter('div[id]').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var placement = 'left';
    if (id.indexOf('server_') == 0) {
      placement = 'right';
    }
    $(this).popover({
      placement: placement,
      trigger: 'hover'});
  });
```

Alternatively, there is 
[JQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/)  --

Specifically --

[Tooltips](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)